# Improve perfomance of my threejs

Tags: camera, rotation, three.js

I have some issues about my model. Is is an easy model buy I can not make It work well...

I upload my project here: http://webgl.drapps.info

I have a car model with some pieces that change material when mouse is over them. I use threex.domevent.js library with "on" function. My model is loaded by json files.

### Issue 1

when mouse is out of canvas, threejs detects that mouse is over a piece of my model, but this is not true, and that piece change its material (triggering mouseOver event).

Furthermore, I tried to get better mouseover event because even when mouse is really over a piece, that event doesn't trigger.

### Issue 2

This is about TrackballControls. Is there any way to control rotation of my world? I mean: rotation only in one axis, rotation only for 180 degrees, etc... Is there any tutorial or article to learn how to rotate and translate camera?

Thanks for everything, I will so please to anybody who wants answer this... because I am a little lost

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you are out of luck.

**Question 1**. Yikes! You are using `threex.js` which is a third-party app that hasn't been updated in almost a *year*, so I can't help you with that.

You are also using an older version of `three.js`. Please update to the current version.

If you still have problems, post a new question with a simple demo -- not your entire project. Better yet, Google your question first.

**Question 2**. `TrackballControls` is not part of the library -- it is part of the examples -- so it is not officially supported. If you are not happy with it, you will have to hack the code yourself.

This question has come up a lot. Google it. To the best of my knowledge, there is not a good solution.

Personally, I would use `OrbitControls` in your case -- it keeps the scene right-side-up, and you can constrain the *maximum polar angle*, keeping the camera "above ground".

The best examples/tutorials are the official `three.js` examples, which will work with the current version of the library.

Comment: Thank you for all this advise... I'll test OrbitControls. Thank you so much, you were so helpfull. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with issue 1.

Issue2:

I am also working on a project to visualize vehicles and needed to be able to rotate. I also tried Trackballcontrolls but it did not suit my needs.

What I ended up doing was creating a a master Object3d and then instead of adding objects/models to the scene, I added them to the master Object3d. That way to rotate everything in the scene, I just had to rotate the master object.
To actually do the rotation I just used the code from one of the cube examples.